# Set HTML background as two triangles

Tags: css, html

I am trying to set my HTML background in a way that it looks like it consists of two triangles but I cannot seem to get it to fully fit the page. How would I accomplish that and additionally be able to set a custom color for both?

Here is the code I am working with:

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  height: 800px;
  width: 800px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: grey;
  margin-left: -0.4%;
  margin-top: -0.4%;
}

#container:before { 
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 28%;
  top: 28%;
  width: 1200px; 
  height: 1200px; 
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); /* fallback */
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

I tried changing all the height and width to 100vh and 100vw but that did not seem to help and there is no option to get the colors changed. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Liamm12/kkt1kd34/

I hope this what are you looking to do

I just set up the body height:100%; and Width:100%; the page will take the full screen

We should add min-height: 100% to the container it will helps the body to be full screen

And finally I just added padding-bottom to container:after it will makes the design as triangles

```css
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width:100%;
            margin: 0;
        }

#container {
  position: relative;
 min-height: 100%; 
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #645384;
}

#container:after { 
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
    padding-bottom: 141.42136%;
  left: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f37638;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="container"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Give some explanation please. We need more than just a bunch of code.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with the  `background: linear-gradient()`:

```css
html, body {margin: 0; width: 100vw; height: 100vh}

body {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(50%, Salmon), color-stop(50%, Khaki));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, Salmon 50%, Khaki 50%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top left, Salmon 50%, Khaki 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, Salmon 50%, Khaki 50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer this question, I have used multiple techniques:

1. Create the aspect ratio box: This is necessary for second steps (since I need a square for this to work.
   For more information, you can look through this: [Aspect Ratio Boxed](https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/)
2. I have used CSS border triangle in order to provide what you are requesting. Look for more detail here: [CSS Triangle](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/)

So what I have done is, creating a square box, setting the border to make the arrow. I have also made the jsfiddle for you to look through.

https://jsfiddle.net/vqmjyjhw/

I have also add css variable on top to help you modify the box fast if you need to:

```
:root {
  --width: 100%;
  --halfWidth: 242px;
  --topColor: red;
  --bottomColor: blue;
}
```

With width variable, you can use %. But in order for the trick to work, halfWidth need to be in px. You can use some extra javascript to calculate exactly what is the width of your container to set halfWidth properly.